# SQL WHERE Query, editing an existing query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I am completing a piece of work and one of the team members who was in charge of SQL has gone on holiday.
I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    Car.*, 
    Building.*, 
    CarType.* 
FROM 
    Car 
    INNER JOIN Building ON 
        Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID 
    INNER JOIN CarType ON 
        Car.CarType=CarType.TypeID
```

this is returning all of the information we need it to about the cars and buildings, however, we need to edit the query so depending on the value of a field in the Request table, called status, if this field is not = 'Accepted', then do not display the information about the buildings or cars?

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    Car.*, 
    Building.*, 
    CarType.*, 
    Requests.* 
FROM
    Car 
    INNER JOIN Building ON 
        Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID 
    INNER JOIN CarType ON 
        Car.CarType=CarType.TypeID 
WHERE 
    Requests.Status <> 'Accepted'
```

However this does not work 
any help would be appreciated
thank you

Comment: You are including data from the Requests table but not actually including it in your query. How does the request table link to Cars Table and or Buildings table?. I am assuming for requests not accepted you wish to return no rows

Comment: In relational database, we use join to retrieve data from multiple tables but these table must have some form of relationship, such as Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID. How does the request table related to the car or building tables? There is no answer if such a relationship does not exist. Would you care to show the table structure of the request table.

Answer (score 0):

Following Query Will  return only Car , Building and cartype information Where status is only 'Accepted' not other then

```
SELECT Car.*, Building.*, CarType.*
FROM Car INNER JOIN Building 
ON Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID INNER JOIN CarType ON     
Car.CarType=CarType.TypeID 
/* add here joining of Requests Table */
WHERE Requests.Status = 'Accepted'
```

**Update:**

```
/* add one line from below lines into the just below where Clause 
 as per your Table hierarchy */
INNER JOIN Requests.ReqID= Car.ReqID 
INNER JOIN Requests.ReqID= Building.ReqID
INNER JOIN Requests.ReqID= CarType.ReqID
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer however when i try this i get the following error:         Unknown column 'Requests.Status' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Scott that is because you did not add Requests Table joining in your Query join also Requests Table

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Requests table from your Query. Assuming that there is a field RequestID in the Car Table your query should look like

```
SELECT Car.*, Building.*, CarType.*
FROM Car 
INNER JOIN Building ON Car.BuildingID=Building.BuildingID
INNER JOIN CarType ON Car.CarType=CarType.TypeID
INNER JOIN Requests ON Car.RequestID = Requests.RequestID
WHERE Requests.Status = 'Accepted'
```

Notice I have joined the Requests table to the Car table Assuming both contain a field called RequestID